# Validate a model has only one type of a relation in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a scenario where I am trying to validate that new Contacts can have multiple Email Addresses added to them - however that each Contact can only have one of a certain Email Address Type.

I.e. I want to create *Contacts* with multiple *Email Addresses*, but they must have an *Email Address* which has an *Email Address Type* of 'work'. They can have zero email addresses or multiple, but always (and only) one work email address.

My models are below. Note, email addresses can be related to objects other than Contact, hence the morphMany.

Contact.php

```php
public function emailaddresses()
{
  return $this->morphMany('EmailAddress', 'emailaddressable');
}
```

EmailAddress.php

```php
public function emailaddressable()
{
  return $this->morphTo();
}

public function emailaddresstype()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('EmailAddressType', 'email_address_type_id', 'id');
}
```

EmailAddressType.php

```php
public function emailaddresses()
{
  return $this->hasMany('EmailAddress', 'email_address_type_id', 'id');
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.1. Any pointers about where to start with this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a function within the object model that stores email addresses `function storeEmail()`, for example.

Within it, check the email address type on input. If the model that you are working with already contains an associated email of that type, default. Otherwise store the address of the given type.

```
function storeEmail($type, $address){
    //Check if the type exists within the retrieved object

    //If it already exists or if the object is missing a work email, default

    //Otherwise add the data to the database for the given object
}
```

When the model is initially constructed, you can add the required work email for the first input.